# Unable to use domain name as replcement for ws protocol ip

Tags: http, websocket, dns, ip

I am using a websocket connection with an ip address like `ws://172.168.41.61`. It is working fine. Now I want use the same service from an Android/IOS application, so I purchased a domain say, `mydomain.example`. Now I linked the above ip to this url: `api.mydomain.example`. But when I tried to use `ws://api.mydomain.example` it is not working as a replacement for the above IP address.

I have following 2 concerns:

1. Is it safe to deploy IP address (`172.168.41.61)` directly in the app for any API or websocket connection. (I guess no, because IP may be difficult to manage or bad practice, offcourse IP will be static)
2. Although I have tested the domain (`api.mydomain.example`) to IP conversion and the IP address is same as expected, then why can't I use the domain like `ws://api.mydomain.example` as a replacement for `ws://172.168.41.61`?

This the site from where I check the domain to IP conversion: 
https://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php

[image]

Comment: Add troubleshooting information as text, not as an image.

Comment: You are (badly) obfuscating things so noone can look and try instead of yourself. And you are not giving clear details on what you did exactly and what happened, like actual error messages. First use `dig` or any online troubleshooting tool to make sure your name resolves correctly. If resolution is fine, then you have a connection problem, maybe depending on how the webserver receiving the request is configured (is it configured to know about this name?)

Comment: The Problem is simple, domain is converting to IP but when I tried to replace the IP with the domain like ws://api.mydomain.com it is not connecting. Image shows that the domain is pointing to the IP, I am asking help about 2 concerns. The answer of 1st concern can be yes/no and the answer of 2nd can be something related to asking exactly what info is needed more to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now. There may be 2-3 issues because of which it was not working earlier:

1. Domain pointing takes some time. (But I waited for atleast 1-2 hour after pointing the domain and still it didn't work). May be it take more than that, sometimes.
2. May due to cache issue, when I tried the first time, the no response thing is cached and it continued to show the same thing even after 2-3 hour.
3. Although I confirmed the domain to IP is converting fine, still the cache in the my system was preventing me to access the original resource.

Thanks